# Getting information from a cisco / juniper router with java

Tags: java, telnet, expect, information-extraction

What method could I use to login to a Cisco or Juniper routers? I know I can use telnet to make a connection to the router itself but I am not aware of an API or anything that allows me to login non-interactively. So how could I do this?

Are there any libraries I can use to achieve this?

I have seen people use scripts that implement things like `expect` to know when to send the username and the password. But that is for shell scripting. How can I do this in java? I would prefer to keep strictly in java too.

**The goal of this is allow a java program login into a router so I can query the router for interface states and execute commands on the router.**

Any ideas?

Comment: seems a bit broad at this point. can you narrow down?

Comment: I want to have a java program login to a cisco router so I can query the router for statuses of interfaces.

Comment: why can't you for SNMP directly then.. why to login and check status of interfaces ??

Comment: SNMP would be okay, but I only want to check the status of an interface on demand. For example when the user triggers and event from a GUI. Also I want to be able extract information like the IP address on the interface and any errors the interface may have taken.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use some Java library for doing the same. http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/jssh/ is a good Java SSH client. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/ has a good telnet implementation

Answer (score 0):

As far as extracting information, you should be able to do it by using SNMP to query the router. Pretty much everything is available over SNMP. Now, as far as command execution, there are SNMP set commands used to "write" information to a router, but you will need to look into that more carefully as I doubt the full command set can be replaced with SNMP set commands.

For Cisco, find out what the IOS image filename is for your device, then you can get the MIB file here: http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/MIBSupport.do?local=en&step=3. Review the MIB file and you will see what is available via SNMP for that device.

You should be able to do something similar for Juniper on their site.

Now, I don't know much about Java, but I do know that there are SNMP libraries available for it (like http://www.snmp4j.org/ ).

With that you will not need to worry about logging into the router, or about any interactive stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, in the case of Cisco, it's common to connect using a serial port on a PC directly into the service port on the router.  This connection uses a programming protocol called IOS.

The easiest way to utilize this is with a programming language called `expect`.  This name describes the language in that you `expect` to get a prompt from the port and then you respond.  Sending that message (your response), you `expect` to get another response, to which you respond, `ad completum` - my term ;)

Note that this cable is proprietary to Cisco, I'm sure there are pin-outs available though.

Finally, it would be possible to emulate this program on java, via a serial port library.

Comment: I would use a cable but I am in another state than the router. Im in Ohio, its in Illinois.